# How to set WINJS Listview items as selected?

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to set several items as selected in a listview from the WINJS library, and also in some other cases to select all the items.

This is sort of what I am looking for

```
document.querySelector("#mylistview").winControl.itemDataSource.list.SelectAll()
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#mylistview").winControl.itemDataSource.list.foreach(function() { this.selected() } )
```

I believe this should be easily done..but well it is microsoft..

Any help?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to select only some of the items? I can do it with the selection.set() function passing the index of the item, but can't manage to find out what is the position of the item I want to select in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection is owned by the view, so you can call selectAll() on the ListView:

You can see the selection property documentation here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211852.aspx

The methods available on the selection object are documented here:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872204.aspx

document.querySelector("#mylistview").winControl.selection.selectAll(); should work for your case.